# A variation of a codomain fibration

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category with pullbacks, let $Arr(\mathcal C)$ be its [arrow category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category).
The functor $cod\colon Arr(\mathcal C)\to\mathcal C$ that takes an object of $Arr(\mathcal C)$, i.e. a morphism in $\mathcal C$, to its codomain is a canonical example of a [Grothendieck fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration). The cartesian arrows are exactly the pullback squares.

There is an easy generalization of this fact. Take any category $\mathcal D$ a functor $F\colon D\to C$ and consider the [comma category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category) $id_{\mathcal C}\downarrow F$. The objects of $id_{\mathcal C}\downarrow F$ are arrows $g\colon c\to F(d)$, the morphisms are pairs $(f,h)$, where $f$ is a morphism in $\mathcal C$, $h$ is a morphism in $\mathcal D$ and 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
c@>f>>c'\\
@VgVV@VVg'V\\
F(d)@>>F(h)>F(d')
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

There is an obviously defined functor $cod_F\colon id_{\mathcal C}\downarrow F\to\mathcal D$ that takes $g\colon c\to F(d)$ to the $d$ object and a square like the one above to the $h$ morphism.

Note that [$id_{\mathcal C}\downarrow id_{\mathcal C}\simeq Arr(\mathcal C)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Arrow_category) and that $cod_{id_{\mathcal C}}\simeq cod$.

**Question**: What is the appropriate reference for the fact that $cod_F$ is a fibration?

I need this fact in a paper I am writing, the paper is intended for an audience that will probably not accept that this is "easy to check" or something.

Comment: Shouldn't this follow from the pullback stability of Grothendieck fibrations?

Comment: @ArnaudD. What do you mean? The functor $\mathrm{cod}_F$ is the strict pullback of $\mathrm{cod}$ along $F$.

Comment: Yes, this works fine. The comma category is naturally a lax pullback, but every lax pullback is constructed as a strict pullback of an arrow category.

Comment: @Pece Oh right, I hadn't thought of that. I was thinking about $\operatorname{cod}(F)$ as a "lax pullback" of $id_\mathcal{C}$ along $F$.

Comment: @asdq Yes, this is what I was missing. Thank you. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will be happy to accept it.